# Why I cannot deny access to /var/www/html/index.html in httpd in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, ubuntu-14.04

Here is my setting for the global

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Require all denied
</Directory>
```

but if I change the filename of index.html to index1.html, then it works.

The virtual host configuration is default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Don't you have other commands which could conflict with it ? can't you post your virtual host configuration ?

Comment: Perhaps the browser youre testing with is caching the content?